# Change columns presentation based on available size

Tags: css, flexbox

Im trying to have a layout like in the image. In desktop show 4 items, but if the browser is resized and there is less space show 2 items above 2 below. And if the browser is even more rezied on mobile for example show only 1 item per row.

Im trying with this code but its not working. Do you know how to achieve that? Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="item ">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  width:33%;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  width:33%;

  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
    width:33%;

  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
    width:33%;

  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y809xwfj/

[image]

Comment: Try deleting `flex-wrap:wrap;`

Comment: read all the answers until the end of the duplicate

Comment: You might want to use media queries to determine the size each box shall have when resizing. One of many ways to tackle this and you'll get full control.

Comment: Thanks but without flex-wrap the items appear on the same row.